# ListView is displaying data which isn't stored in the database

Tags: c#, database, listview

My program displays player scores with an alias of their choice, problem is I have loads of test runs stored in the database so i deleted all the entries of the table but they are still displayed in the list view?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public partial class Leaderboard : Form
{

    public Leaderboard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=F:\Graded\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\bin\Debug\SusData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

    private void Leaderboard_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //try catch for opening the connection to the database
        try
        {
           con.Open();//Opening the connection to the database
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Application.ExitThread();//if the database can't be opened the application will exit
        }
    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Alias, Score FROM HighScore ORDER BY SCORE ASC");//SqlCommand allows for SQl commands to be used in the code of c#
        try//try catch for loading the users highScores
        {

            SqlDataReader DR = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (DR.Read())
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(DR["Score"].ToString());//Filling the list view with users Scores
                item.SubItems.Add(DR["Alias"].ToString());//Filling the list view with users Alias
                listView1.Items.Add(item);//Adding everything

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);//Messagebox in case theres an error loading the scores to the ListView

        }
    }
```

I have two tables in the database and the players scores and alias' are stored in the HighScore table.

Answer (score 0):

you should explicitly use your SqlConnection (in a `using` block) around your SqlCommand code. Not sure which connection you're executing against when you do your query.

Comment: I thought i was doing this?
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM HighScore ORDER BY Score ASC", con);

Comment: That's the command, but which connection is it using to execute the command? You should put a breakpoint and inspect to see for sure, but best is to wrap your cammand with a `using` and explicitly set the connection. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460659/c-sharp-sqlcommand-connection-open-issue

Comment: so you're saying the SqlConnection which is declared at the top of the class is wrong?